# Route Matching HERE intermediate links

Tags: routes, here-api

Is it possible to get the intermediate HERE links of the car route generated by the HERE Route Matching API? Only links that match with sent coordinates are returned by the API at the moment. See example image of the link what I want to get:

Check this example image: https://ibb.co/ChxM0Vp

Many Thanks!

**Update 03/03/2022**

Thank you for replying.
In the command line example you posted, if i send one coordinate i get the corresponding matched link. This is was expected.

Nonetheless in the RME Basic Demo screenshot i posted, we are sending a set of coordinates with the corresponding timestamp.
As a result, what we can see visually, using the RME Demo, is that the sent coordinates have their matched link as well as intermemediate link segments between 2 matched coordinates. This can be seen in the screenshot, and suggests that, in this Demo, somehow the most likely route is being identified and marked in blue as we can see. Also the initial and end of the intermediate segments can be seen visually.
All this suggestes that in this Demo, somehow the intermediate link segments between 2 matched link ids are being identified although the Link IDs are not being shown.
Could it be that more than one API is being used in this case, let's say routematching for the coordinates matching with link Ids and another API (or some other approach) to get the intermediate segments. The reason i'm asking is that in the map shown in the screenshot, the intermediate link segments can be seen and also the most likely route, is drawn in the map.
I apreciate any input on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get any link only by one coordinate as well, see example for curl:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://routematching.hereapi.com/v8/match/routelinks?apikey=...your_apikey...&routeMatch=1&mode=car' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw 'LATITUDE,LONGITUDE
53.3737131,-1.4704939'
```

In the response you will see only one linkId.

Comment: Please see my updated question.